# Calling function from other C++ source doesn't work

Tags: c++, function, makefile

I've looked at several posts of the same questions on here and as far as I've figured I've done what they said to do. However, I still get a "undefined reference to `cmb::functionA()'" warning.

I have the header:

```
//combine.h
#ifndef COMBINE_H
#define COMBINE_H

namespace cmb 
{
    void functionA();
}

#endif
```

Function source file:

```
// combine.cc
#include <iostream>
#include "combine.h"
using namespace std;

namespace cmb
{
    void functionA()
    {
        cout << "print something\n"; 
    }
}
```

And main:

```
//main.cc
#include "combine.h"
using namespace std;
using namespace cmd;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])            
{   
    functionA();
}
```

It is now working when compiling manually (g++ -o Test *.cc -Wall --std=c++17) but using make still gives me the same error. I really don't understand make files so any help would be appreciated.

makefile:

```
CXX := g++
CXXFLAGS += -Wall -std=c++17

LIBSRCS = $(filter-out main.cc,$(shell find -name \*.cc))
LIBOBJS = $(patsubst %.cc,%.o,$(LIBSRCS))

main: main.o combine.o libproject.a
    $(CXX) $(CPPFLAGS) $(CXXFLAGS) $(LDFLAGS) -o $@ $<

$(LIBOBJS): %.o: %.cc
    $(CXX) $(CPPFLAGS) $(CXXFLAGS) -c -o $@ $<

libproject.a: $(LIBOBJS)
    ar rcs $@ $^
clean:
    rm -f libproject.a $(LIBOBJS)
.PHONY: clean
```

I just use `make main` in terminal.

Comment: You misspelled cmd as cmb in combine.cc

Comment: Fixed it but still get the error (when using make, the g++ command does work??)

Comment: Then the problem is most likely in your makefile, which you have not shown.

Comment: Wait I'll add it to the post, rather unreadable without layout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you use a library, you need to tell the linker to use it (LDFLAGS), and it should be after the main in g++ command. As in previous comments, the using namespace cmd needed to be changed to cmb

This one worked for me:

```
CXX := g++
CXXFLAGS += -Wall -std=c++17

LIBSRCS = $(filter-out ./main.cc,$(shell find -name \*.cc))
LIBOBJS = $(patsubst %.cc,%.o,$(LIBSRCS))
LDFLAGS += -L. -lproject

main: main.o libproject.a
    $(CXX) $(CPPFLAGS) $(CXXFLAGS) -o $@ $< $(LDFLAGS) 

libproject.a: $(LIBOBJS)
    ar rcs $@ $^

.PHONY: clean
clean:
    rm -f libproject.a $(LIBOBJS) main main.o
```

I also needed to add ./ in filtering out main.cc

Example run:

```
jontte@jontte-Latitude-E5420:~/Temp/maketest$ make
g++ -Wall -std=c++17   -c -o main.o main.cc
g++ -Wall -std=c++17   -c -o combine.o combine.cc
ar rcs libproject.a combine.o
g++  -Wall -std=c++17 -o main main.o -L. -lproject 
jontte@jontte-Latitude-E5420:~/Temp/maketest$ ./main 
print something
jontte@jontte-Latitude-E5420:~/Temp/maketest$ make clean
rm -f libproject.a ./combine.o main main.o
jontte@jontte-Latitude-E5420:~/Temp/maketest$
```

Comment: Still same issue? I tried this one before posting, and it worked. I had also to change the using cmd to cmb

Comment: Yes. I really don't get it. I can't just use 'make'  or 'make clean' either. I get `make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found. Stop.` or `make: *** No rule to make target 'clean'. Stop. Aarg
`

Comment: Hmmm, check that indentations are made with tab, not space.

Comment: Check from here, I quickly added my example to github:https://github.com/jontte75/makefile-experiments/tree/master/mk_with_lib

Comment: That one does work! I guess there was something wrong in mine. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

You must add combine.o after main: in the makefile.

Comment: Tried, still: `make main
g++     main.cc   -o main
/tmp/ccP6KeHy.o: In function 'main':
main.cc:(.text+0x1c): undefined reference to 'cmb::functionA()'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
<builtin>: recipe for target 'main' failed
make: *** [main] Error 1`